# Nhibernate ordered paging by a lazy loading bag

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, lazy-loading, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following mapping:

```
<class name="Entity, Namespace.MyDomain" table="Entity" lazy="false" mutable="false" >
<id name="EntityId" column="ENTITY_ID"> <generator  class="native"/> </id>

<bag name="EntityList" inverse="true" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
       <key column="ENTITY_ID"/>
       <one-to-many class="Namespace.Entity.EntityList, Namespace.MyDomain"/>
</bag>
```

Now, I want to get an ordered paging by my EntityList.Name.
For example, if I have 2 entities:
1) Entity with EntityList of animal names (tiger)
2) Entity with EntityList of animal names (cat, dog)
Then, I would like to get the second entity first (because 'c' of cat is lower then 't' of tiger) and the first one afterwards.

Of course, it will affect my paging, because there might be a chance that entity with tiger will be shown on the first page, if i get my paging by by entity.id, but when i get it by entitylist.names, it might be displayed on other page.

Thanks in advance,
Mike.

p.s. - i'm using criteria.

Comment: Why does your internal bag needs to be lazy loaded? by your request, it will always be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var entityIds = session.CreateCriteria<Entity>()
    .CreateAlias("EntityList", "el")
    .AddOrder(Order.Asc("el.Name"))
    .SetProjection(Projections.Id)
    .List<int>();

var entities = session.CreateCriteria<Entity>()
    .Add(Expression.In(Projections.Id, entityIds))
    .SetFetchMode("EntityList", FetchMode.Eager)
    .List<Entity>();

// resort again
return entityIds.Select(id => entities.First(e => e.Id == id)).ToList();
```